# How to create a function for click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a click event, and within the event handler there's a function that I want execute after the click to **change Class of the clicked button** from *A* (by setting timeout) to *B*.

I tried with this, but this didn't work (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFd5K/1/)):

```
Button.click(function(){
    function myFunction(x,y){
        $(this).addClass(x);
        alert(x);

        $(this).addClass(y);
        alert(y);
    }
});


setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction("aaa","bbb");
}, 100);
myFunction("ccc","ddd");
```

How can I get the function work after the click event?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your myfunction() is defined only, if the button was clicked. Try sourcing it out:

```
var Button = $("#button");

function myFunction(x,y){
    Button.addClass(x);
    alert(x);

    Button.addClass(y);
    alert(y);
}

Button.click(function() {
    myFunction('aaa','bbb');
});

setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction("aaa","bbb");
}, 100);

myFunction("aaa","bbb");
```

Comment: This code will never run "myFunction" on click, it is immediately  evaluated when the script is loaded instead and "click()" only receives "undefined" instead of a callback function

Comment: Thank you Chris! sorry but the click doesn't work! "I want to execute function after the click to change Class of the clicked button".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for. It's similar to the other answers but only calls the function when the button is clicked.

```
var button = $('button#test');

function myFunction(x,y){
    button.addClass(x);
    alert(x);

    button.addClass(y);
    alert(y);
}

button.click(function(){
    myFunction("aaa", "bbb");
});
```

I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mFd5K/3/

Comment: Thank you so much but I want to use `setTimeout` to change Class. Following your what you suggestedat all times I have to click to change class.

Comment: You can probably just move the `setTimeout` call into the `click` callback function. I'm not 100% sure on what you're trying to achieve, but I hope you can get to the correct answer from here :)

Answer (score 0):

The function `myFunction` is defined in different lexical scope.

Use this instead:

```
//You don't want to define the function each time the button is clicked
function myFunction(x,y){
    $(this).addClass(x);
    alert(x);

    $(this).addClass(y);
    alert(y);
}

Button.click(function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        myFunction.call(butto, "aaa","bbb");
    }, 100);
});
```